# Unwrap the array type of data firestore query returns

Tags: java, firebase, hashmap, google-cloud-firestore

This returns me an ArrayList containing the image Uris I have stored in Firestore. How could I unwrap the array list and extract them one by one?Below is the sample output of logcat.

{0=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app........, 1=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app........., 2=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app}

```
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Ads").whereEqualTo("user_id",user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                            ArrayList<String> imgUri = (ArrayList<String>) entry.getValue();
                            for (String uri : imgUri) {
                                Log.d(TAG, uri);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR7w6.png)

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo please check my updated question. I just added. Thanks

Comment: @AlexMamo I just updated the code in the question to show u.Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the error at a line from my code? `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap` I cannot see any `HashMap` in this code. Can you place indicate the exact line where you are getting this error?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes I am getting the exception exactly from this line.                              ArrayList<String> imgUri = (ArrayList<String>) entry.getValue();

Comment: I'll rewrite you the code right now.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you so much It works now! no enough reputation to upvote you. Thank you

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
rootRef.collection("Ads").whereEqualTo("user_id", user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) document.get("imgUri");
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, entry.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The output will be:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app.........,
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app........., 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app.........,
```

Comment: I am getting this exception. java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: I have tested my self and it worked. Have you added the cast `(ArrayList<String>)`? Can you please show me the changed code by editing your question?

Comment: My mistake, sry, it was not an array, it was an object. Please see my updated answer, should work now, right?